# Weak solution of a non-linear problem with Lipschitz functions

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the problem 9.5 in Evans PDE book. The statement goes as follows:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a $\Lambda$-lipschitz bounded function with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)>\lambda_1$, where $\lambda_1$ is the first eigenvalue of $-\Delta$ on $H_0^1(\Omega)$. We consider the problem $-\Delta u=f(u)$ in $\Omega$, $u=0$ on $\partial\Omega$ and $u>0$ in $\Omega$. 
I have to use the method of sub-supersolutions to solve the problem (find a weak solution). My idea is taking as a supersolution the function vanishing on the boundary such that $-\Delta u=M$, where $M$ is a sufficiently big constant. Using the maximum principle this function is positive. The subsolution should be something like the first eigenfunction, which is positive. The problem is that I can't show that it's a subsolution.
It's evident that $\lambda_1<\Lambda$, but the inequalities go in the wrong way in order to show that the first eigenfunction is a subsolution. I can't use Taylor expansion with this Lipschitz function, I only know that $|f(z)|\leq\Lambda|z|$.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Try and show that for small $s>0$, $\lambda_1 s\leq f(s)$ and use it to show that for some $\delta>0$, $v=\delta\phi_1$ is an sub-solution.

Comment: Thank you, nice idea, now it's easy!

Comment: You are welcome @JuanC